# Disable html5 "Required" field input attribute when section of form is not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

The section below should only appear if the user selects the "Yes" option. This section  (id="co-op") is embedded inside of a long Form. All of the inputs within the section are required (using HTML5 "Required" attribute). However if the user selects "No" the section below doesn't display within the form. This means that I would like to disable the "Required" fields within the section when the user selects "No"; since they can't view the inputs. Currently they are still submitting and preventing a successful submission. 
 Thanks!

```
    <section id="co-app">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fullName">Co-Applican'ts Information</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required>     
                        </div><!--/form-gp-->
                    </div><!--/col-md-4-->  
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="middleName" placeholder="M.I." maxlength="1" id="middle-name" required>   
                        </div><!--/form-gp-->
                    </div><!--/col-md-1-->  
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" required>        
                        </div><!--/form-gp-->
                    </div><!--/col-md-1-->  
                </div><!--/row-->   
            </div><!--/container-->
        </section><!--/co-app-->
```

Comment: You probably should be making them `disabled`, which will prevent them from being submitted and also from being considered actually required, regardless of the state of the `required` property.

Comment: So, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @DavidThomas - I'm looking for a jQuery solution that will prevent the fields from being submitted when the section is not visible.

Comment: I appreciate what you want, but to get any useful answers you need to demonstrate an attempt at solving your own problem, show us where you get stuck, what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the jquery validation engine plugin I was able to use the following jquery to toggle the hidden elements when selected and remove the "required" attribute when not selected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#retired-select-coapp, #retired-select-primary ").change(handleNewSelection);
    // Run the event handler once now to ensure everything is as it should be
    handleNewSelection.apply($("#retired-select-coapp, #retired-select-primary"));

    /** Step One Co-App Info  **/
    $('#co-app').hide();
    $(".app-choice").change(function () { //use change event

    if (this.value == "option2") {
    $('#co-app').stop(true,true).slideDown('1000'); //than show
    $('#co-app input,#co-app select').addClass('validate[required]');

    } else {
    $('#co-app').stop(true,true).slideUp('1000'); //else hide
    $('#co-app input, #co-app select').removeClass('validate[required]');
}
});
```